# Can't get index

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, datagrid

I have a column in a dynamic DataGrid that displays the date and time. I am trying to only get the date to display.

```
DataRowView drRow = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
        DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
        int index = dg.Columns.HeaderIndex("Date");
        if (index > 0 && drRow.Row.Table.Columns.Contains("GateIn"))
        {
            DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(drRow["GateIn"]);
            e.Item.Cells[index].Text = dt.ToShortDateString();
        }
```

It's not finding the index so it jumps out of the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the headerindex was wrong. It shouldn't have been Date

```
int index = dg.Columns.HeaderIndex("Gate In");
            if (index > 0 && drRow.Row.Table.Columns.Contains("GateIn"))
            {
                DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(drRow["GateIn"]);
                e.Item.Cells[index].Text = dt.ToShortDateString();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try searching the index by the column index(e.g. 0 for first column, 1 for the second etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to first extract DataTable from DataGrid. Like:

```
DataTable dt = DataGrid.DataSource as DataTable
```

Now you can inspect the data table variable dt.